# Initialize a property in Entity Framework that already has a constructor

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there ANY way to initialize a property in an Entity Framework entity that has a collection?

This is the generated code for an Entity that has a collection:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntity()
    {
       this.MySubEntities = new HashSet<MySubEntity>();
    }

    public bool IsActive {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<MySubEntity> MySubEntities {get; set;}
}
```

If I need to make a new `MyEntity` that I want to default to `IsActive = true`, it cannot be done!  (Unless I edit the T4 template.)

**Please tell me there is a way to default `IsActive = True` without editing the generated file (or the T4).**

Note: I have AutoMapper making the entity for me, so `new MyEntity {IsActive = true}` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Without editing the T4, I don't see what you can do.

So you could change your T4 to generate something like that (initialize null lists in getter instead of doing that in ctor)

```
private ICollection<MySubEntity> mySubEntities_;
public virtual ICollection<MySubEntity> MySubEntities {
   get {
        return mySubEntites_ ?? (mySubEntites_ = new HashSet<MySubEntity>());
   }
   set {
       mySubEntities_ = value;
   }
}
```

then you wouldn't need the empty ctor in the generated class, and could have a partial class with an empty ctor, doing what you need

```
public MyEntity() {
   IsActive = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure... but I will give you some directions so you can take a look.

If you set your default value on your database to IsActive = true I believe EF handles this by itself. If not, I'm pretty sure you can set the default value on the Designer.

I think you can also do another constructor because this are partial classes.

you might read this :[How to set default value for POCO's in EF CF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137738/how-to-set-default-value-for-pocos-in-ef-cf) may give you more insight.

another solution, (practical but not good and didn't answer the question), is to change IsActive to IsInactive so it defaults to false :D - I really do this when design databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the EF model to add default values. In the properties of a column you can find "Default value" and set it to what you want. It is default set to "(None)".