# Using Entity Framework 6 Code First can I specify a default value for a Boolean field?

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF6 and trying to use Code First with Migrations against a SQL DB.

Is it possible using a data annotation in my POCO class to specify that the default value of a Boolean or Bit field should be true?

I know I could modify the data migrations code to add it to the specific migration class but would like to avoid that.

Comment: Set the default value in the ctor.

Comment: I would prefer to set it at the DB level because the DB will be used by other programs which I wont necessarily have control over the constructor of the classes used.

Comment: Currently EF does not play well with the default values set by datatbase. When writing it will always saves the value th property was set to.

Comment: I had the same problem, wanted to set default bool value to "false" for a "IsDeleted" column in my MyObject DB Table and use code first. In my Context class, method "protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)" I added this:  modelBuilder.Entity<MyObject>().Property(p => p.IsDeleted).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed); The problem is that when my delete funcion was setting IsDeleted to "true" and saving, it would always save it as false. I had to remove the feature and change all my booleans to nullable bools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this: [How to set default value for POCO's in EF CF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432857/208922)

You can do this through Migration step.

```
public class Test
{
(...)

public bool TestProperty { get; set; }

(...)
}



public partial class AddTestClass : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "Test",
            c => new
                {
                    (...)
                    TestProperty = c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: false)
                    (...)
                })
            (...)
    }

    public overide void Down()
    {
        // Commands for when Migration is brought down
    }
}
```

`